# systemd networking is ignoring network configuration file on boot

Tags: networking, systemd, systemd-networkd

I have an embedded linux system compiled with Yocto, using systemd.  I have a network configuration file at `/etc/systemd/network/20-wired.network`.  The contents of that file are:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
Address=192.168.5.40/24
Gateway=192.168.5.1
DNS=192.168.5.1
```

However, when I reboot my machine, the eth0 interface is successfully configured using DHCP instead of assigning the static IP address.  The `ip a` command shows:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f8:dc:7a:3c:27:82 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.1.223/16 brd 10.1.255.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 85898sec preferred_lft 85898sec
    inet6 fe80::43ec:fd39:e1c0:3c05/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

However, if I then wait 5 seconds or so after boot, and do a `systemctl restart systemd-networkd` the system will usually be configured correctly like so:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f8:dc:7a:3c:27:82 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.5.40/24 brd 192.168.5.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::43ec:fd39:e1c0:3c05/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Lastly, with the right timing on the restart of the network service, I can seemingly even get this result (both the intended static address and the unwanted DHCP address):

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f8:dc:7a:3c:27:82 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.5.40/24 brd 192.168.5.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.1.1.223/16 brd 10.1.255.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 86246sec preferred_lft 86246sec
    inet6 fe80::43ec:fd39:e1c0:3c05/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Does anyone know what is going on here or how to debug this?  Is there something obvious wrong with my configuration?

`systemctl status systemd-networkd` shows the following immediately after boot (specifically after network-online.target):

```
* systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Tue 2021-07-20 12:58:52 UTC; 65ms ago
TriggeredBy: * systemd-networkd.socket
       Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
   Main PID: 282 ((networkd))
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 3576)
     Memory: 416.0K
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-networkd.service
             `-282 (networkd)
```

Some number of seconds later it looks like this:

```
* systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-07-20 12:58:52 UTC; 3min 20s ago
TriggeredBy: * systemd-networkd.socket
       Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
   Main PID: 282 (systemd-network)
     Status: "Processing requests..."
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 3576)
     Memory: 2.0M
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-networkd.service
             `-282 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd
```

So it looks like the service is still "activating" when the network-online.target services run.  I'm not sure what that means, though, or if it's a problem.

Comment: IS DHCP is setting a `10.1.1.x` address? Are you sure you have the correct gateway? Is your 198.x.x.x. address request valid for your network?

Comment: What does `systemctl status systemd-networkd` return right after reboot (before your restart)?

Comment: @StephenBoston Yes, the 10.1.1.0/16 address is being set by the DHCP server.  It's valid settings for my network.  The 192.168.5.0/24 static address I'm trying to set is "valid" only in so far that I have a computer connected at 192.168.5.2/24.  Gateway doesn't matter at all.  I shouldn't have to have a gateway present to configure the interface.

Comment: @nobody I added status output to the bottom of the post.  The one thing I noticed is that when services which target network-online run, the systemd-networkd service is still "activating".  A few seconds later, that service shows as "active".

Comment: I just noticed that it seems NetworkManager made it on to the most recent build.  It was running alongside systemd-networkd.  Is that normal?  I disabled the service and I'm now correctly configuring the interface.

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed that both systemd-networkd and NetworkManager were running.  That is not normal, right?  Usually you'd want one or the other?  `systemctl disable /lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service && reboot` seems to have fixed the problem.

Edit: This is not the answer, or at least the whole answer.  Just had it happen again even with NetworkManager disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to disable *NetworkManager*.
Just append this line to your configuration file:

```
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

Hope that will help.